# Entity Framework Best Way To Represent Arbitrary Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking for a database solution in which some parts of my data may become unstructured.

More specifically, I'm using Entity Framework 6, but really I suppose this is more of a SQL rooted question.

Suppose I have a collection of generic geometric objects (GeoObj) that can be represented by an arbitrary amount of values (collection of int).

This is one solution, but I'm really not sure about the correctness/efficiency:

```
GeoObj
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<GeoValue> Values { get; set; }
}

GeoValue
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem I see is that since I expect a lot of GeoObjs, and each GeoObj has a good amount of GeoValues, the GeoValues Table with get HUGE.

Will this slow down performance significantly?

Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What's unstructured about it? And what is "HUGE", or "performance"? As compared to what? And under which circumstances? It's impossible to answer this.

Comment: trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in your suspicion that the potential performance issue is ultimately rooted in your SQL database server. Are you using MS SQL Server?

The answer will be found in testing the performance of your specific version of SQL Server running on the hardware and configuration of the machine hosting the database.

As far as I know, Entity Framework doesn't have facilities that support control of table partitioning and things like that to work around the bottleneck of a **HUGE** table. That is in the scope of the database.

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx for some info on that.